# Mongo driver not working with wamp 32 bit

Tags: php, mongodb, windows-8.1, database

I have 64 bit operating system and 32bit wamp(php 5.5.6) i have installed the mongo driver for php but its not working correctly.I have also tried all [Mongo Driver](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) given version with the wamp but its not working.Any one working with this? When i click on the wamp and go to php extensions php_mongo is checked but not show the loaded in phpinfo().

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases